# Hibernate - How to load a Collection of ids for a ManyToMany relation without load the whole object with Lazy strategy

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a JPA entity (Group) with a collection (Device) inside of it (a ManyToMany relation). For the Group, sometimes I need to run a FindAll with the full object with the collection of Devices fully loaded. Another time I just need to run a FindAll that loads Group, but the collection of Devices should be just a list of ids. How can I do that? I am using Spring Boot with Spring Data and Hibernate.

Device:

```java
@Entity
public class Device {
    @Id
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    private String id;

    private String name;

...

}
```

Group:

```java
@Entity
public class Group {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
       name = "group_device", 
       joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id"), 
       inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "device_id"))
    private Set<Devices> devices;

...

}
```

GroupRepository:

```java
public interface ShortenRepository extends CrudRepository<Shorten, String> {

    // This return the list of groups and also the list of Devices related to each one
    @Query("select g from Group g join Device d")
    public List<Group> findAll();

    // This return the list of groups and also the list of Devices ids instead of the full Device object.
    // This query should be faster because Hibernate just needs to check the inner table ('group_device') to fetch the Devices ids
    // instead of fetching the whole devices info in the Device table.
    @Query("select g from Group g join Device d")
    public List<Group> findAllOnlyDevicesId();
```

Comment: you cannot make the field `private Set<Devices> devices` be a set of id's and a set of Devices at the same time. This won't work. You need to create another field for purely IDs

Comment: Exactly, I would like to know the valid approaches for this problem. Adding a list of purely IDs, how could this approach works in terms of mapping and queries?